# Highchart and json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, database, highcharts

My JSON looks likes this, and I want to make a Highchart, showing show many signups that have been each hour. So my X-axis would be a count of the number of timestamp with the same day and hour.

```
[{"data":"2016-04-11 20:18:41"},{"data":"2016-04-11 20:18:41"},{"data":"2016-04-11 12:18:40"},{"data":"2016-04-11 13:18:40"},{"data":"2016-04-11 13:18:34"},{"data":"2016-04-11 14:18:34"},{"data":"2016-04-11 15:18:34"},{"data":"2016-04-11 15:18:30"},{"data":"2016-04-11 19:18:29"},{"data":"2016-04-11 19:18:29"},{"data":"2016-04-11 20:18:18"},{"data":"2016-04-11 21:18:12"},{"data":"2016-04-11 22:18:09"},{"data":"2016-04-11 23:18:08"}];
```

I'm pretty stuck. It seems like the JSON is formatted in a wrong way or something.

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('json/json.php', function(data) {
    //console.log(data);
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'test'
      },

      series: [{
        name: 'signups',
        data: data,
        turboThreshold: 0
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

---

#### Edit

I managed to make my data like this:

```
[{"TS":"2016-04-12 00:00:05","COUNT":"187"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 01:00:30","COUNT":"75"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 02:00:56","COUNT":"32"},
```

How does I make it as X and Y values in my chart?

Comment: yep. incorrect format. have a look at the documentation for correct format

Comment: I just dont understand that my chart dosnt show anything, and im not getting any errors

Comment: It's not showing any values, because you haven't provided any values. You have a list of dates, with no corresponding data values - the chart has nothing to show, but there is no error to show either.  If you want to show how many occurrences of each date there are, you will have to process your data and determine that.  Then send the data to the chart in the proper format.

Comment: So i need somthing like this? [{"2016-04-11 20:00:00","8"},{"2016-04-11 21:00:00","11"}], Timestamp and value

Comment: The data is in incorrect format. For highcharts to understand your date time format, you would need to create date object before you pass it to highcharts or convert it to timestamps (epoch milliseconds). Also, highcharts does not understand the keys 'TS' and 'COUNT', use x and y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using Highstock, so your data should be given as Timeseries (time, value).

Let's take your example:

```
yourData = [{"TS":"2016-04-12 00:00:05","COUNT":"187"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 01:00:30","COUNT":"75"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 02:00:56","COUNT":"32"}....]
```

should look like:

```
[[time1.TS, value1.COUNT], [time2.TS, value2.TS], [time3.TS, value3.COUNT]] // pay attention it's an array of arrays.
```

This simple function should be able to formatting your data as needed:

```
var formattedData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < yourData.length; i++){
    formattedData.push([ new Date(yourData[i].TS).getTime(), parseInt(yourData[i].COUNT)]);
        }
```

I've made a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/b6yd50sh/3/), so you can see it working.

Hope I have helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the JSON object-array into a nested-array. The first index will be the timestamp, and the second will be the count.

```js
var data = [{"TS":"2016-04-12 00:00:05","COUNT":"187"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 01:00:30","COUNT":"75"},{"TS":"2016-04-12 02:00:56","COUNT":"32"}];

// Used to transform the AJAX loaded data into stock data.
function processData(data, xField, yField) {
  return data.map(function(obj) {
    return [ new Date(obj[xField]).getTime(), parseInt(obj[yField], 10) ];
  });
}

$(function() {
  //$.getJSON('json/json.php', function (data) {  // We will ignore the AJAX call for now.
    data = processData(data, 'TS', 'COUNT');      // Process the data.
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
      rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Sign-up Counts by Date'
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Date of Sign-up'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: {
          text: 'Count'
        }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Sign-ups',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
  //});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: My data are timestamp for when a user have signed up to a campaign. I want to show how many have signed up pr. hour with a graph